# WIX Single Package Installer - Per machine Shortcuts

Tags: wix, windows-installer, shortcut, wix3.11

I followed [this](http://www.egoroff.spb.ru/blog/62003.html) for getting a functioning Per-User/Per-machine installer working using ALLUSERS=2. Now, my issue is regarding getting shortcuts working properly with this setup. If I set MSIINSTALLPERUSER=1 (Single User) then my Desktop and StartMenu shortcuts are always added per user in the HKCU. If I set MSIINSTALLPERUSER={}, then I can get shortcuts per machine. In the custom UI, MSIINSTALLPERUSER is being set based on the selected radio button in the advanced portion of the UI. So, although the shortcuts are created last and their registry values are set to HKMU, the installer always chooses where to put the shortcuts based on the initial value of MSIINSTALLPERUSER.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to properly creating shortcuts based on the type of install selected in the advanced UI (Per User / Per Machine).

Here is my Product.wxs
`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>        
    <Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">      
        <Product Id="*" Name="HearCon" Language="1033" Version="2.0.299" Manufacturer="Tremetrics" UpgradeCode="73765816-7ba9-4a2b-89c3-ce1f26863b53">

        <Package InstallerVersion="500" Compressed="yes" />    
        <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />

        <Condition Message="Only Windows 7 and newer are supported">
            <![CDATA[Installed OR VersionNT >= 601]]>
        </Condition>

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="Application" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="HearConGroup" />
            <ComponentRef Id="RA660Folder_Permission" />
        </Feature>
        <Feature Id="DesktopShortcutFeature" Title="Desktop Shortcut" Level="1">
            <ComponentRef Id="DesktopShortcut" />
        </Feature>
        <Feature Id="StartMenuShortcutFeature" Title="Start Menu Shortcut">
            <ComponentRef Id="ProgramMenuShortcut" />
            <Condition Level="1">Privileged</Condition>
        </Feature>

        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Name="HearCon" />
            </Directory>
            <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" Name="Desktop" />
            <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder" />
            <Directory Id="CommonAppDataFolder">
               <Directory Id="RA660Folder" Name="RA660">
                   <Directory Id="RA660Driver" Name="Drivers" />
               </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>

        <Property Id="WixAppFolder" Value="WixPerUserFolder" />
        <Property Id="ApplicationFolderName" Value="HearCon" />
        <Property Id="ALLUSERS" Value="2" />
        <Property Id="DISABLEADVTSHORTCUTS" Value="1" />
        <Property Id="MSIINSTALLPERUSER" Value="1" />
        <UIRef Id="WixUI_CustomAdvanced" />
        <WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="HearConBanner.bmp" />
    </Product>

    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="DesktopFolder">
            <Component Id="DesktopShortcut" Guid="10E3E42D-8B2E-471D-A6F9-6263C3491D4C">        
                <RegistryValue Root="HKMU" Key="Software\Tremetrics\HearCon" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" />
            </Component>
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
            <Component Id="ProgramMenuShortcut" Guid="2C7EA878-B1B1-4B64-937A-6B583ED5E9B3">       
                <RegistryValue Root="HKMU" Key="Software\Tremetrics\HearCon" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" />
            </Component>
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="RA660Folder">
            <Component Id="RA660Folder_Permission" Guid="0A538414-E53F-470E-9546-7EF193878F05">
                <CreateFolder>
                    <util:PermissionEx User="Users" GenericAll="yes"/>
                </CreateFolder>
            </Component>
       </DirectoryRef>
   </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

`

Comment: What do you mean by `HKMU`, maybe `HKCU`?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski HKMU as the Registry root value. Setting as so is supposed to add the registry entry as HKCU if install is per user, and HKLM if per machine.

Comment: Do you have a business case to support a per-user installation?  Historically Per-Machine installation has been a better model for Windows Applications.  Per-User is more typical for applications that are spread by word of mouth by users who don't have admin rights on their own machine.  Per machine is intentionally distrubted and supports all users on the machine.

Comment: Our business case is that so many of our clients run into problems installing simple applications like this one due to the need of admin rights. So, historically, we’ve been using squirrel.windows to give a simple install experience. As the popularity of our app has grown, we’ve run into the issue of large clients with several users on the same machine having the issue of having to install a dozen times. So, now I’m trying to provide a best of both worlds option.